Insertion in distributed data tables for multiregion click house deployment
Say I have two regions - DC1 and DC2 . Let's consider that I have 9 nodes in DC1 and DC2 with 3 replicas in each DC for 5 shards. In this case , if I trigger an insert statement to a distributed table via java client or a http call to one of the servers in DC1 , how do I ensure that the healthy node chosen to perform this insert is within DC1? Does Clickhouse handle this automatically or do we need to give that intelligence during the query time via some approach?

Please see the ClickHouse load_balancing setting: https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/operations/settings/settings#load_balancing.  Note that the insert has to eventually happen on all replicas regardless.

For a multi-region deployment you'd be better off relying on internal replication, writing into dc and allowing it to replicate. If you write through the distributed table (with internal_replication:false) your replicas will eventually diverge. I would leave reads to the distributed table and use another distributed table  for writes to one DC1 - but it depends what failover guarantees you need.

@GeoffGenz I did have a look at this documentation but there is no option like local_quorum in case of Cassandra , where we shall instruct the host receiving the query to be responsible for having this write guaranteed in 2 out of 3 nodes within the same datacenter like DC1. All the options in the load balancing are tilted with a possibility of a cross region node being chosen as a healthy host as there is no proximity check or load check done to choose this . Do you have any idea on how we shall achieve this otherwise?

You can do a proximity check by manipulating the nearest_hostname setting, possibly manipulating the DNS names you use for your nodes.  I've done it before for queries.

Thanks for suggestion @GeoffGenz . I will check and see. levenshtein distance and nearest hostname look almost the same but with a little difference. But I see that the default is always local replica. If the local replica is not there , will clickhouse automatically choose the load balancing strategy or it will spawn out to a node in other DC in case of a miss?

you also could use INSERT ... SETTINGS distributed_sync=1, distributed_quorum=2 to ensure your insert was stored on minimum 2 replicas in shard
